# How do you debug Azure SQL trigger?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms

SSMS used to have a Debugger (prior to version 18), but even that only works with local installations of SQL Server. But how do you debug a trigger in Azure SQL database? SSMS Debugger cannot be hooked up to it, and I can't find any other tools.

Comment: I've never found the TSQL debugger remotely useful. What type of thing are you trying to debug? Just copying the code out of the trigger and mocking up `#inserted`/`#deleted` triggers in place of the pseudo tables would likely do the trick? Or performing an action in Azure that fires the trigger and capture the actual execution plans dependant on what you are looking into exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried debugging a trigger on an Azure Sql Database table (from Visual Studio 2019).  The message received is: the Debugger does not work with Azure Sql DB tables.

You can try adding this code to the trigger to raise an error message which may help with debugging:

```
Declare @ErrorInfo varchar(8000)

Set @ErrorDetails = Char(13) + 'Inserted: ' + Char(13) + IsNull ((Select * From Inserted FOR JSON AUTO), '')

RaisError ('Error details: %s', 15, 1, @ErrorDetails)
```

More details on how to use [RaisError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: That might actually be good enough, thanks! Best part is that it shows up when just doing an update query, no need to go to sys.messages

Comment: I am glad it was helpful.  You can also select from the Deleted table.  More details on Inserted and Deleted table: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15